# SelectMany - project to new type?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a linq expression

```
Dim sources = details.Datasources _
                     .SelectMany(Function(s) _defs.Item(s.Name)) _
                     .Select(Function(d) New AliasedDatasource With {.Alias = "", .DefDetails = d}) _
                     .Where(Function(s) s.DefDetails.Dataview = dataview) _
                     .Select(Function(d) d)
```

Notes:

- details.Datasources is an IEnumerable
- each Datasource has a "Name" and "Alias" property
- each DefDetails contains a "Key" property (amongst other stuff)
- _defs is an ILookup and therefore a list of lists
- datasources may have the same name and therefore _defs.Item(s.Name) could return several lists of lists

I am trying to

1. flatten the ILookup for those entries whose name matches the Datasource name
2. create a new custom type which combines the datasource.Alias with the DefDetails returned.

In the line

```
.Select(Function(d) New AliasedDatasource With {.Alias = "", .DefDetails = d}) _
```

I am effectively trying to do this

```
.Select(Function(d) New AliasedDatasource With {.Alias = s.Alias, .DefDetails = d}) _
```

but obviously the s.Alias is not visible to that lambda.

So how should I rewrite this to achieve what I am after. I wondered if actually there was an Overload on SelectMany which would allow me to project onto a new type but I am struggling to work it out.

Many thx

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query syntax is your friend here:

```
Dim sources = From s In details.Datasources _
              From d In _defs.Item(s.Name) _
              Where s.DefDetails.Dataview = dataview _
              Select New AliasedDatasource With { _
                                                  .Name = d.Name, _
                                                  .Alias = s.Alias, _
                                                  .Key = d.Key, _
                                                  .DataviewKey = d.DataviewKey _
                                                }
```

The `From .. From` construct is compiled as `SelectMany`. The items in the `Select` clause determine which overload is taken.

Comment: although I tend to prefer the lambda syntax, your solution is much more understandable. Thx

Comment: I used to prefer lambda syntax too, but esp. with `Selectmany`, but also with joins or groupings I tend to use query syntax because lambda syntax can get really clunky there.

Answer (score 1):

OK. So I found the overload and it 'simplifies' down to ...

```
Dim sources = details.Datasources _
                     .SelectMany(Function(s) _defs.Item(s.Name).Where(Function(d) d.DataviewKey = dataview),
                                 Function(s, d) New AliasedDatasource With {.Name = d.Name, .Alias = s.Alias, .Key = d.Key, .DataviewKey = d.DataviewKey})
```

Thx